# What are TCS conjectures that were proved for primes and small values but then turned out to be false?

Tags: big-list, primes

Are there any conjectures in theoretical computer science that involve some parameter n and were proved for small values of n AND for primes but later turned out to be false?

In number theory such problems do exist, eg. as [Aaron Meyerowitz points out](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117891/what-are-conjectures-that-are-true-for-primes-but-then-turned-out-to-be-false-for/117985#117985) the one about the coefficients of the cyclotomic polynomials. From TCS I only know examples like the [Evasiveness Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aanderaa%E2%80%93Karp%E2%80%93Rosenberg_conjecture) that are still unsettled.

Answer (score 3):

Note: This is more like an extended comment than an answer.

Here is a problem from combinatorics whose status is similiar in flavor to that of Evasiveness Conjecture:

> **Background**. A Latin square of order $n$ is an $n × n$ matrix in which each element from {1, . . . , n} occurs exactly once in each row and column. Two Latin squares of order $n$ are said to be orthogonal if you get $n^2$ distinct ordered pairs when you superimpose them. A set of Latin squares are said to
>   be mutually orthogonal if every pair of them are orthogonal. Let $N(n)$
>   denote the maximum number of mutually orthogonal Latin squares of order
>   $n$.

It is known that $N(n)\leq n-1$ for all $n$. If $n$ is a prime power then we know that $N(n)=n-1$, but for general values of $n$ the status of lower bounds is wide open.

Comment: Not quite completely wide open. It's been known that $N(6)=1$ since 1900 (G. Tarry), that $N(n) \geq 2$ for $n>6$ since 1960 (Bose, Shrikande, Parker), and that $N(10)<9$ since 1989 (Lam, Thiel, Swiercz).

Comment: Thx Jagadish, the problem is that this is something that is conjectures to hold only for prime(power)s. I am looking for something that WAS conjectured to be true for all numbers but turned out to be false.

Comment: @domotorp Yes, my response doesn't answer the question exactly. I'm curious to know if there are any such examples myself, so +1 for your question.

Answer (score 3):

In a related not-quite answer to @jagadish's, after being defined, [Costas arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costas_array) were quickly found for very small numbers, and were later found for sizes $p-1$, where $p$ is prime.  However, it is open whether they exist for all $n$ and computer searches are making people believe that they do not exist for $n=32$.